# Problem When Accessing MAPI properties from C#

Tags: c#, com, vsto, mapi

We are having a repeated exception occur in our error log whilst accessing MAPI properties.

Our VST0 2005 Outlook addin is experiencing problems at a particular site. The addin is running on a 64bit exchange terminal services environment there within Outlook 2003.

I am getting the following error: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry.get_MAPIOBJECT()..."

We am seeing this error repeatedly. The funny thing is the addin was running fine on this box until a couple of months ago.

The underlying class we are using to access MAPI was provided by Helmut Obertanner here: http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1112. It has worked just fine up until now.

Can any bright spark out there help me out with this one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things the Outlook API won't let you change (making it read-only)

It's really frustrating sometimes.

For that, a lot of people use a library called Redemption:
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/

I've used it a long time ago and have only good things to say about it.

Comment: as our existing code is working 99% of the time i didn't really want to go for redemption. a fix for the current code would have been preferrable. i'll try to get hold of helmut the author.

Answer (score 0):

It's really tough to say without seeing a bit more code, but a bit of a guess here, addresses change, some are added and some are removed.  Even just moving an address will change it's entryid.  So, it may be that you have saved and trying to use a long obsolete address entryid.  Insure you are acquiring fresh entry ids.